# How to hide the top page navigation on tablet home screen?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, home-screen, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I am a new user of Galaxy Tab and I noticed in comparison with some other home tab screen-shots in another forum, that my tab is the only who has the top page navigation squares shown.

I have only one page like the image below and my question is how can I hide that square too? I am running ICS.

[image: Home screen Screen shot]

Comment: Maybe try an alternative home launcher than the stock one? What you're seeing is probably part of Samsung's version of the home launcher.

Comment: @BryanDenny the truth is that this is the stock rom. Can you give me a clue about the home launchers please ?

Comment: On Android the home screen (a.k.a. "Launcher") is just another app.  There are a myriad of replacements available for download on the Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=launcher+replacement+-theme&c=apps  Some are free, some are paid.  You can have as many installed as you wish, and set one of them as default (it will ask you when you first open it.)

Comment: @Kaoukkos what Chahk said... you can replace just about any app in Android, including the actual "home launcher". When you install one and then press your "home" button, it will ask you which launcher you want to use (and set as default).

Comment: My Asus Transformer Prime (ICS) has the same top bar -- Google search at the left, screen index in the center, and "all apps" icon at the right, so that is probably standard ICS behavior.   I had to double-check on mine, I hadn't noticed the dots in the middle, as my background photo is very light in that area.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments - this is just the launcher you are running.

There are many different launchers you can try which may look slightly or completely different.

Some good launchers to try are:

- [Chameleon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chameleonlauncher&hl=en)
- [GO Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.go.launcherpad&hl=en)
- [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher)
- [TSF Shell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tsf.shell)

Comment: Also I'm recommend to look on ADW Launcher.